# How to copy text from Microsoft Word to Notepad++ preserving non breaking spaces?

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++

I am trying to copy text from Word to Notepad++, but Notepad++ does not retain non-breaking spaces.

The Notepad++ text file I am inserting into has the UTF-8 BOM encoding. If I add non-breaking spaces within Notepad++, the program keeps them all right.

I also tried Edit → Paste Special → Paste RTF Content, but no go.

Comment: As a workaround you can replace all non-breaking spaces in word to character not used otherwise (e.g. # § ¤ ..., or even a sequence "<NBS>"), then in notepad++ replace it back to non-breaking space

Answer (score 2):

#### This is caused by Microsoft Word. PowerPoint in the middle does the trick.

When copying from Word, text version of the clipboard (which N++ uses for Paste) is always created **without** non-breaking spaces. But on copying from PowerPoint, non-breaking spaces are kept. And this can be used for the trick.

1. Copy the text in Word (as usually).
2. **Paste in PowerPoint.**
3. **Copy in PowerPoint.**
4. Paste in Notepad++ (as usually).